# print out all website directories names

Tags: php

If i've the following main directories into my website

```
/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir3/
/dir4/
```

Is there any php function or code can print all directories names once i execute it. ~Thanks

Comment: Are you asking us to write/find the code for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scandir` to list files and directories within a directory. You can check which is which you can use `is_file` and `is_dir`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that what i really needs :) it would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

`glob` should be able to help you with this ([php-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php))

with something like:

```
$folders = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```